# How can I 'grep' files in a Git repository?

Tags: git, grep

I love [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) to search in all files checked in to a repository. It's great. But is it possible to use it (or some other Git command) to just use to find files (independent of content)?

At the moment I do this:

```
find . | grep middleware
```

which works, but it's not using the Git index which means it's going through every found file and it reports on files that are matching the `.gitignore`.

Are there some clever tricks?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may want `git ls-files` which lists the files in the index (and automatically adjusts for your current directory inside the Git work directory).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I would do git ls-files | grep 'name you're looking for' to filter on the big list of files git ls-files will return.  (I also alias ls-files to ls because I use it frequently)

Comment: We can do it with the command ``git ls-files "*.sh"`` or ``git ls-files | grep .sh``

Comment: I've long had the alias: `find = ! git ls-files | grep`, but sometimes I would really like to limit the search to a particular path, e.g., `git find foo bar/baz`.  Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: To answer my own Q, here's what I've come up with `find = ! sh -c 'git ls-files $2 | grep $1' -`

Comment: @JFlo I implemented your request in [this commit](https://github.com/mirabilos/git-find/commit/9e1eef8161f9834c5c20b1569d42af0f8f8c9a9d) in `git find`, hope that helps!

Comment: @mirabilos, That looks useful.  Do you have plans to get git-find into the git upstream?

Comment: @JFlo yes, but no luck so far; if you can manage it, be my guest… I structured the repository so merging will be painless

Comment: @Chu-SiangLai, note that `grep .sh` doesn't only match `foo.sh`, it also matches, say, `fashion.h`, because `.` is a wildcard in regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 27):

I think `git ls-files` will do the trick for you.

So:

```bash
git ls-files "*middleware*"
```

Comment: +1 for that. I always did 'git ls-tree -r HEAD|grep "toSearchFor"'

Comment: That's really cool too but with `git ls-files | grep ...` I get the power of grep right at my finger tips and since I have colour highlighting on by default on grep it displays nicer.

Comment: @PeterBengtsson the [`git find` I wrote (and which someone downvoted for unknown reasons today)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42149326/2171120) is basically `git ls-files | grep` but with find-like syntax (and it can even delegate to find, still avoiding non-git files)

Answer (score 6):

You might consider a non-Git solution in this case.

**`find`** itself has the ability to do what you want in a more efficient manner than piping its results into `grep`:

```bash
find . -name 'middleware*'
```

You will need to quote the pattern so that the `*` isn't expanded by the shell before being passed to `find`.

There is a powerful program called **`ack`** that is, well, [better than grep](http://betterthangrep.com), and one of my favorite uses for `ack` is exactly what you've mentioned—finding files that match a pattern within a tree. `ack` uses [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) regular expressions ([PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)), not shell fileglobs, though.

```bash
ack -g middleware
```

If you want to search *within* those files, `ack` lets you do that more easily than writing a shell loop over the results of `find` that `grep`s within each file. Compare the two and see which one you prefer:

```bash
for f in $(find . -name 'middleware*')
do
    grep 'pattern in file' $f
done
```

versus

```bash
ack -G 'middleware' 'pattern in file'
```

I highly recommend `ack` as something to add to your toolkit.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for introducing me to `ack`! Just want to note: "The `-G` option has been removed. Two regular expressions on the command line was considered too confusing; to simulate `-G`'s functionality, you may use the new `-x` option to pipe filenames from one invocation of ack into another." from [`ack(1)`](https://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.22-man.html). If I figure out the fix, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Note that `for f in $(find ...)` [is an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Much better practice to `find . -name .git -prune -o -name 'middleware*' -exec grep 'pattern in file' {} +`, which also gives you roughly the same advantages xargs does in only starting the fewest possible instances of `grep`, and replicates one of the advantages of `git grep` of not spending time searching through the `.git` directory.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pure Git solution

`git grep` has built-in support to limit the grep to a glob of files. **The other answers all use external tools to do the actual grepping, which misses the point.**

Example from the `git grep` [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep).

```bash
git grep 'time_t' -- '*.[ch]'
```

> Looks for time_t in all tracked .c and .h files in the working directory and its subdirectories.

From the option descriptions.

> `--`
> Signals the end of options; the rest of the parameters are  limiters.

> `<pathspec>…​`
> If given, limit the search to paths matching at least one pattern. Both leading paths match and glob(7) patterns are supported.

So to translate your example (which did not include something to limit the search however so I added it here):

```bash
find . -name '*.txt' | grep middleware
```

You would do:

```bash
git grep middleware -- '*.txt'
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. OP is asking for a git-limited flavor of `find` in the same sense that `git grep` is a git-limited flavor of `grep`. i.e., OP wants to search git-tracked files by name, not by contents.

Comment: '*.[ch]' is a `find` like filter on the file name.  `man gitglossary` and search on pathspec.  It may not be equivalent to find.  But in such cases, a non-limited human can type `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Git now has a matured search functionality (as the previous poster mentioned). You can search file names, extensions, by programming language, etc. You can search inside at file contents, etc.

You search when you log into GitHub, at the search field in the upper left of the screen.

See this for details:
*[Searching code (legacy)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-code)*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem regularily, and I just went and hacked [`git find`](https://github.com/mirabilos/git-find) – if you don’t use the [Debian package](https://www.mirbsd.org/%7Etg/Debs/dists/lenny/wtf/Pkgs/git-find/) you can just copy the `git-find` script to `/usr/lib/git-core/` (or comparable) and enjoy it.

It can be used in several modes, the easiest of which is indeed:

```bash
git find \*middleware\*        # or
git find '*middleware*'        # which is short for
git find -name '*middleware*'
```

Combining is also possible (and almost as flexible as regular `find`, you just have to write the `-a` explicitly):

```bash
git find \( -name \*.java -o -name \*.js \) -a ! -ipath \*/test/\*
```

It has a couple more options, most of which handle with filtering the name or full (partial, i.e. below the current working directory) path, some of them case-insensitively (`-iname` and friends), and two global options, one to toggle regexp between POSIX Basic (default) and POSIX Extended, the other toggles symlinks (default on); this finds only files (and symlinks), not directories or submodules (“gitlinks”) by design.

It can also pass the file list to regular [find(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/find) if it’s not too long (it must be passed on the command line), which allows for things like…

```bash
git find -- -mtime -100
```

… at slight filesystem cost (`find` does access the filesystem), but on the other hand, almost all (not search depth-specific stuff) of `find` works, and you only get to operate on files “in the index”, i.e. known to git (present in the HEAD commit or `git add`ed).

It’s a bit picky about unresolved conflicts though. If you notice any problems with it, just drop me a note (here, or via IRC).

PS: Feel free to lobby the official git people to subtree-merge the git-find repository, I’d be more than happy to have it integrated into git proper (the licence is even more liberal, you just need the `mksh` shell in a somewhat recent (50 should be sufficient) version, but it’s the most widespread Unix shell nowadays so that’s okay).